# Translating parts of Mustache.js Templates

Tags: javascript, php, internationalization, mustache

So I am basically trying to translate some words that I have previously hardcoded into a Mustache.js template.

The template:

```
... <button type="button" class="btn" data-id="{{id}}">Delete</button> ...
```

The problem:

Every other aspect of the website can be translated on the fly into a number of various languages, but keywords such as "Delete", "Create", "Edit" etc have been hardcoded in the template and are never translated.

Question:

How do you translate these words, as opposed to hardcoding them?

What I have tried:

I have been playing around with string replace functions in javascript on the template before I call Mustache.render, like this:

```
// Simulate array of translations coming from server (in the current users locale)
this.i18n = new Array();
this.i18n['delete'] = '[en_GB] Delete';
this.i18n['create'] = '[en_GB] Create';
this.i18n['edit'] = '[en_GB] Update';

$.get(template, function (template, textStatus, jqXhr) {
    var html = $(template).filter('#artist_collection').html();
    // ...
    html = html.replace('Delete', this.i18n['delete']); // <- There may be several of these depending on the page/template
    // ...
    var template = Mustache.render(html, data);
    index.artist_container.append(template);
    console.log(html);
});
```

This works, but is it a good approach? Is there a better solution?